# Launch another app from android 11 widget?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-widget

## I can't launch widgets on android 11.

> This code works on my android 9 phone,
> but android 11 Google Pixel 3a emulator not working.
> what should I do for this.
> Ok, so what I want to do is create a widget that will simply launch another application when the widget is pressed.

> Widget Xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:text="Whatsapp Launch"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </Button>

    <Button
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:text="Spotify Launch"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </Button>
    

</LinearLayout>
```

> Widget Class

```
class SimpleAppWidget : AppWidgetProvider() {

    override fun onUpdate(
        context: Context,
        appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
        appWidgetIds: IntArray
    ) {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        for (appWidgetId in appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId)
        }
    }

    private fun updateAppWidget(
        context: Context, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
        appWidgetId: Int
    ) {

        // Construct the RemoteViews object
        val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.simple_app_widget)
        // Construct an Intent object includes web adresss.

        val launchIntent12 = context!!.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.spotify.music")
        val launchIntent122 = context!!.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.whatsapp")
        // In widget we are not allowing to use intents as usually. We have to use PendingIntent instead of 'startActivity'
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, launchIntent122, 0)
        val pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, launchIntent12, 0)
        // Here the basic operations the remote view can do.
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, pendingIntent)
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button2, pendingIntent2)
        // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you will need to add [package visibility rules to your manifest](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility). As it stands, `getLaunchIntentForPackage()` is probably returning `null`. After fixing this, fully uninstall and reinstall the app before continuing.

Also:

- Use unique IDs for your `PendingIntent` objects (they are both set for `0` in the second parameter to `getActivity()`)
- Consider using `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` for the fourth parameter to `getActivity()`

Comment: I applied your feedback and ran it again but android 11 still didn't work .

Answer (score 0):

WİDGET Activity

```
  class SimpleAppWidget : AppWidgetProvider() {

override fun onUpdate(
    context: Context,
    appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
    appWidgetIds: IntArray
) {
    // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
    for (appWidgetId in appWidgetIds) {
        updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId)
    }
}

@SuppressLint("RemoteViewLayout")
private fun updateAppWidget(
    context: Context, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
    appWidgetId: Int
) {

    // Construct the RemoteViews object
    val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.simple_app_widget)
    val launchIntent2 = context!!.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.spotify.music")
    val pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, launchIntent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button2, pendingIntent2)

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

widget permissions

```
<queries>
    <package android:name="com.spotify.music"/>
    <package android:name="com.example.widget11" />
    <intent>
        <action android:name="com.spotify.music" />
    </intent>
</queries>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Widget11">
    <receiver android:name=".SimpleAppWidget">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/simple_app_widget_info" />
    </receiver>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```